# Sums of these 2 Series and their Physical Meaning

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

will the following converge if they then  what are their sums

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{e}\right]^n$

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[\frac{\left(1+{1}/{n}\right)^{n+1/2}}{e^n}\right]$

do the above series have any physical meaning (apart from fun).

Answer (score 3):

The partial sums are increasing and are bounded above by $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[\frac{\sqrt{8}}{e^n}\right] = \frac{\sqrt{8}}{e-1} \approx 1.646\ldots $ so they converge.

They in fact converge to just under 1.23 and 1.63.  I would not expect there to be a physical meaning.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You can use the [root test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test) to prove the convergence.